# Numpy/PyTorch method for partial tiling

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting, pytorch

I seem to recall encountering a Numpy or PyTorch method similar to `numpy.tile`, except that it allowed partial tiling to reach specified dimensions. So if I had

```
a = np.array([[5, 6, 7, 8],
              [1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

(or, correspondingly, `t = torch.Tensor(a)` if this is a PyTorch method),

then

```
a.mystery_method((3,4))
```

would produce output

```
array([[5, 6, 7, 8],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

Unfortunately, I now can't find this method in the Numpy or Pytorch docs. Does it actually exist, and what is it if so?

Comment: @Divakar That's it, thanks! Was trying ```a.resize()```, which is different... Please post as an answer so I can accept.

Comment: So, the second input argument e.g. `4` in the posted sample, would always be same as the number of cols, right?

Comment: Yep. Thanks for the analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.resize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html) -

```
M = 3 # number of rows for output
np.resize(a,(M,a.shape[1]))
```

Another way with [`np.take`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) or simply indexing along the first axis for performance -

```
np.take(a,np.arange(M)%a.shape[0],axis=0) # with np.take
a[np.arange(M)%a.shape[0]]                # with indexing
```

Runtime test -

```
In [91]: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(2000,4000))

In [92]: M = 3000

In [93]: %timeit np.resize(a,(M,a.shape[1]))
10 loops, best of 3: 24.1 ms per loop

In [94]: %timeit np.take(a,np.arange(M)%a.shape[0],axis=0)
100 loops, best of 3: 16.2 ms per loop

In [95]: %timeit a[np.arange(M)%a.shape[0]]
100 loops, best of 3: 15.2 ms per loop
```

Comment: A warning - in older versions, `np.resize` had problems with referencing and slicing the created or original array and would throw `ValueErrors` that were difficult to trace.  [`ndarray.resize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.resize.html#numpy.ndarray.resize) still has this problem as per the docs.